# Accepting hex values from commandline in msi installer

Tags: installshield, installshield-2015

I am creating a msi installer using InstallShield 2015, I need to pass a hex value to the installer via command line as given below

```
msiexec /i setup.msi LCID=0x9
```

This LCID will get written into the registry in a DWORD type variable. However, I noticed that it will work only if i pass a decimal. Is there any way I can pass a hex value to the installer and write into the registry?

Comment: What is the difference between the decimal value `9` and the hexadecimal value `9` ?

Comment: @Luuk , It was just an example

Answer (score 1):

The public property(LCID) passed from command-line accepts parameter as string/integer only. In registry configuration, you must have defined DWORD value whose data is [LCID]. By default, the value passed from command-line will be converted to hex while being saved in registry as it's type is DWORD. In your case, hex is passed from command-line and it can't be converted to hex as per default behavior.

If you still want this behavior for this specific registry, i would recommend managed code custom action which will accepts command-line input and create registry as you want.